# jquery upload with blueImp - success function

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using blueImp jquery file upload plugin, based on the "[Basic Plus](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html)" demo version. I have removed the `multiple` word from the input tag, such that only a single file can be uploaded (the image is meant for a profile image for a user).

Below is the jquery I have - again, exactly what is in the [sample file](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html), except for (a) the `multiple` attribute removed , and (b) the target `url` for upload is changed.

What i am having trouble, is with the success function. When the file (successfully!) uploads - nothing happens.  ie - the 'Abort' button just stays put, and nothing else happens.

--> So my question is either (1) what does my upload function need to return, so that the existing script can give some sort of user feedback/success message; 
or (2) what modification needs to be done in the script below, so that a message of sorts can tell the user that the upload succeeded?

What i would really like, is because its for a profile image - is that the user can decide to again change the image (re-upload).

what i have returned right now, is the following JSON:

```
[{"name":"08.09.2014_15.48.47_7IhYm.jpg","size":52170,"url":"\\uploads\/08.09.2014_15.48.47_7IhYm.jpg","thumbnail_url":"\\uploads\/08.09.2014_15.48.47_7IhYm.jpg","delete_url":"upload2.asp?islem=delete&id=9","delete_type":"POST"}]
```

Existing jQuery code:

```
        $(function () {
            'use strict';
            // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
            var url = 'ULfile2.asp',
                uploadButton = $('<button/>')
                    .addClass('btn btn-primary')
                    .prop('disabled', true)
                    .text('Processing...')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        var $this = $(this),
                            data = $this.data();
                        $this
                            .off('click')
                            .text('Abort')
                            .on('click', function () {
                                $this.remove();
                                data.abort();
                            });
                        data.submit().always(function () {
                            $this.remove();
                        });
                    });
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                autoUpload: false,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
                // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
                // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
                // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
                disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                    .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                previewMaxWidth: 100,
                previewMaxHeight: 100,
                previewCrop: true
            }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    var node = $('<p/>')
                            .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
                    if (!index) {
                        node
                            .append('<br>')
                            .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
                    }
                    node.appendTo(data.context);
                });
            }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
                var index = data.index,
                    file = data.files[index],
                    node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
                if (file.preview) {
                    node
                        .prepend('<br>')
                        .prepend(file.preview);
                }
                if (file.error) {
                    node
                        .append('<br>')
                        .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
                }
                if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
                    data.context.find('button')
                        .text('Upload')
                        .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    if (file.url) {
                        var link = $('<a>')
                            .attr('target', '_blank')
                            .prop('href', file.url);
                        $(data.context.children()[index])
                            .wrap(link);
                    } else if (file.error) {
                        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                        $(data.context.children()[index])
                            .append('<br>')
                            .append(error);
                    }
                });
            }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
                    $(data.context.children()[index])
                        .append('<br>')
                        .append(error);
                });
            }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
                .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
        });
```

Comment: Have you written or using an off-the-shelf server-side upload handler?

Comment: Written my own. the server side works perfectly, uploads the file, and spits out the above mentioned JSON

Comment: Then the answer is in the `.on('fileuploaddone'` section of the jQuery handler. If you return a clean `url`, it should create a link. If you return an `error`, you should get a message indicating so.

Comment: so just a `url` needs to be returned? not that whole JSON?

Comment: No, you can return whatever you like via the server-side script. The jQuery handler above is what processes the returned `data`. The `url` node of your returned JSON is converted to a link according to the `fileuploaddone` event.

Comment: I see. i just noticed that i am getting an error in the console: `TypeError: a is undefined` referring to jquery.min.js  -- i am wondering if my JSON format above is not correct?

Comment: The JSON looks to be in the proper format. If you have doubts, you can always use this: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: OK, solved it - i was missing the initial `files` at the beginning of the JSON.  thanks for pointing me in the right direction!